# What is the purpose of weights and biases in tensorflow word2vec example?

Tags: machine-learning, tensorflow, deep-learning

I'm trying to understand how [word2vec example](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/r0.9/tensorflow/examples/tutorials/word2vec/word2vec_basic.py) works and don't really understand what is the purpose of weights and biases passed into nse_loss function. There are two variable inputs into the function: weights (plus biases) and embedding.

```
# Look up embeddings for inputs.
embeddings = tf.Variable(
    tf.random_uniform([vocabulary_size, embedding_size], -1.0, 1.0))
embed = tf.nn.embedding_lookup(embeddings, train_inputs)

# Construct the variables for the NCE loss
nce_weights = tf.Variable(
    tf.truncated_normal([vocabulary_size, embedding_size],
                        stddev=1.0 / math.sqrt(embedding_size)))
nce_biases = tf.Variable(tf.zeros([vocabulary_size]))
```

Both are randomly initialized and (as far as I understand) both are subject to updates during learning.

```
# Compute the average NCE loss for the batch.
loss = tf.reduce_mean(
  tf.nn.nce_loss(nce_weights, nce_biases, embed, train_labels,
                 num_sampled, vocabulary_size))
```

I suppose both of them should represent trained model. However weights and biases are never used later on for similarity calculations. Instead, only one component is used:

```
# Compute the cosine similarity between minibatch examples and all embeddings.
norm = tf.sqrt(tf.reduce_sum(tf.square(embeddings), 1, keep_dims=True))
normalized_embeddings = embeddings / norm
valid_embeddings = tf.nn.embedding_lookup(
  normalized_embeddings, valid_dataset)
similarity = tf.matmul(
  valid_embeddings, normalized_embeddings, transpose_b=True)
```

So what about second component of the model? Why weighs and biases are being ignored?

Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In word2vec what you want is a vector representation of words. In order to do that you can use, among other things, a neural network. So you have inputs neurons, outputs and hidden layers. What you do to learn the vector representation is to have a hidden layer which number of neurons is the same as the dimension you want in your vectors. There is one input per word and one output per word. And then you train the network to learn the input from the output but in the middle you have a smaller layer which you can see it as a codification of the input in a vector. So here are the weights and biases. But you don't need them later, what you use for testing is a dictionary which contains the word and the vector which represents that word. This is faster than running the neural network to get the representation. That is why you don't see it later.

The last code you write about the cosine distance is to know which vectors are closed to your calculated vector. You have some words (vectors) you make some operations (like: king - man + woman) and then you have a vector that you want to convert in the result. This is the cosine function run among all the vectors (queen would have the minimum distance with the result vector of the operation).

To sum up, you don't see the weight and bias in the validation phase because you don't need them. You use the dictionary you have created in the training.

**UPDATE** s0urcer has explained better how the vector representation is created.

The input layer and the output layer of the networks represents words. It means the value is 0 if the word is not there and 1 if the word is there. First position is one word, second another one, etc. You have as input/output neurons as words.

The middle layer is the context, or you vector representation of the words.

Now you train the network with sentences or group of consecutive words. From this group you take one word and set it in the inputs and the other words are the outputs of the network. So basically the network learns how a word is related with other words in its context.

To get the vector representation of each word you set the input neuron of that word to 1 and see the values of the context layer (the middle layer). Those values are the values of the vector. As all the inputs are 0 except the word that is 1, those values are the weights of the connections of the input neuron with the context.

You don't use the network later because you don't need to calculate all the values of the context layer, that will be slower. You only need to check in your dictionary what are those values for the word.

Comment: I see what you mean, but in this case input per word and output per word are random values from embeddings. Usually, during learning process only weights and biases of the layers are being updated. But in this case (what confuses me) learning process updates inputs, outputs (which are both coming from different parts of embeddings) as well as weights. And moreover, learning seems to be random since weights are random for each word. Am I missing something?

Comment: They are not random values, they are values selected randomly. When you have a data set and you are going to run the algorithm for several epochs what you do is to randomize the order of the dataset every epoch, that is why the values are randomly selected.
Weights are random at the beginning and then are modified by the optimizer in every batch. They are randomize at the beginning to avoid get stuck in local minimums.

Comment: It's pretty mind-blowing to me. Do you mean we don't need weights since we need only relationship information between words, not 'absolute' values?  And in such math operations all weights would cancel out?

Comment: No I didn't mean that. Word2Vec try to create a vector representation of words. NeuralNetworks are one way but there are more. So basically the neural network is to learn the the vector of each word. Then you use a dictionary which stores the relationship between words and vectors. That is all. So you don't need the weights of the neural network later to have the vectors because you use the dictionary. You could use the neural network but probably it will slower.

Comment: OK, I understand that part. But weights and inputs are updated with every epoch simultaneously. To me they look equally important. And weights are not being used for relation calculations. I can see only two reasons why: either weights cancel out or we don't loose much information by stripping down part of the model. Is this correct intuition?

Comment: @WarGoth I have told you several times, weights are used to learn the vectors per each word. Once you learn the vectors you don't need the weights anymore and they don't use them in the example.

Comment: Sorry for being meticulous. I'm really trying to understand mechanics of it and get intuition. Thank you for the conversation, I think I understand internals better now

Comment: This isn't entirely true - the main reason why the biases aren't needed is because you are only trying to compute distances between words.  So the biases will cancel out when computing distances.  But if you actually need the conditional probability matrix as originally posed in the word2vec paper, then you totally need the biases.

Answer (score 3):

The idea of skip-gramm is comparing words by their contexts. So we consider words equal if they appear in equal contexts. The first layer of NN represents words vector encodings (basically what is called embeddings). The second layer represents context. Every time we take just one row (Ri) of first layer (because input vector always looks like 0, ..., 0, 1, 0, ..., 0) and multiply it by all columns of second layer (Cj , j = 1..num of words) and that product will be the output of NN. We train neural network to have maximum output components Ri * Cj if word i and j appear nearby (in the same context) often. During each cycle of training we tune only one Ri (again because of the way input vectors are chosen) and all Cj, j = 1..w. When training ends we toss the matrix of the second layer because it represents context. We use only matrix of the first layer which represents vector encoding of the words.

Answer (score 1):

Weights and biases are updated here:

`_, loss_val = session.run([optimizer, loss], feed_dict=feed_dict)`

The optimizer does the following - computes the gradient and then does the update step.

The similarity is a separate computation is called in a different location and is used to validate the results. Which happens in the following section of code:

`if step % 10000 == 0:
    sim = similarity.eval()`

The validation of the embedding relies upon the similarity embedding.